# What build.gradle for google mobile vision?

Tags: android, android-vision

I am using google mobile vision, but it is crashing **from time to time** ( a `libc: Fatal signal 11` in com.google.android.gms ). May be I have a bad build.gradle.

build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.mylastname.dcinventory"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

build.gradle (project) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Is there something wrong ?

Note : My device is a Samsung Note 8 (Android 8.0.0).

Comment: You can add build.gradle (Project) ? Maybe you dont add 
`repositories{ google() }`
`dependencies{   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' }`

Comment: I added the project build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the dependencies, because `play-services-vision` might need it:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
```

Comment: @Eric what has `app.iml` have to do with this?

Comment: it seems to be generated by gradle, so I can check play-services-base:15.0.1 has been used without specifying it build.gradle.